# Different C++ compilers in one project? (MSVC and GNU C++ compatibility)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gnu

A very simple C++ question that is more aimed at the compilers:
Suppose I create a static library (*.lib) or a dynamic linked library (*.dll) with the latest Microsoft Visual C++ compiler.

Can I also use such a library directly in GNU C++ compiler projects (within the same operating system) if the header files are available?

That's not compatible with each other, is it? (I'm thinking first of a different ABI etc.)

Many Thanks.

PS: I have an unknown 3rd party library (lib) available. Can I find out here which compiler was used to generate it?

Comment: In the past, it wasn't even possible to combine C++ DLLs built with distinct versions of the MSVC compiler. The usual alternative was to have C DLLs (while the C DLL could be just a binding of the C++ lib.) I'm not sure how much advance has been achieved. FYI: [C++ binary compatibility between Visual Studio versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170). Concerning linking C++ DLLs built with MSVC and g++... I've serious doubts. (Again, I would expect that it can work for C DLLs.)

Comment: "That's not compatible with each other, is it? (I'm thinking first of a different ABI etc.)" In most cases it will not be compatible unless its a pure `c` interface.

Comment: _I have an unknown 3rd party library (lib) available._ Is it closed source? You (or your boss) has purchased it. Ask the vendor. Is it open source? Google for the source code. Is it "fallen from a truck"? Good luck. Maybe, disassemble it or try the usual lib. tools like e.g. [objdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) or [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-170).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat not exactly true, that article is misleading. That is only in regards to C++ stdlib items. C ABI and `virtual` ABI are stable (because COM) and that was always able to be used across versions. Otherwise you'd never be able to use the windows system libs with any project not compiled with that version. In general you could always use headers from a library compiled with an older version, you just couldn't `new` or `delete` an object from it. The library had to do that itself because of layout.